# Should the [cyclic] tag be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There are 166 questions tagged [cyclic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic), but the tag seems useless, because it's completely ambiguous. Each time it's used it refers to something else.

Comment: Maybe [this burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407959/) is relevant :P

Comment: @VLAZ I think you meant to link to something else than this very page?

Comment: @user2373145 No, because then the link wouldn't be cyclic.

Comment: Do { burniate [cyclic] } while (true)?

Comment: @kjhughes https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion

Comment: @Charlieface: https://www.google.com/search?q=do+a+barrel+roll

Comment: Break the [cycle] ?

Comment: A missed opportunity for a pun. Perhaps *"Can we avoid recycling the [cyclic] tag?"* or *"Send this tag to the recycling plant"*.

Comment: I always cringe at the awful puns used on burninate requests, so this title is a breath of fresh air to me.

Comment: @404 same... if you want more to cringe at, I made a [subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/StackOverflowHumor/) for them

Answer (score 16):

Some time has passed and clean-up has been done. See the original answer with updated numbers below. I believe a synonym/merge should now be made from [cyclic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic) to [cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cycle).

---

There are currently <strike>166</strike> 78 questions with [cyclic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic).

- <strike>22</strike> 1 (off-topic) is also tagged [`graph`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic+graph) - should be retagged to [cyclic-graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-graph) (there is even a [directed-acyclic-graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/directed-acyclic-graphs) that might fit for a few).
- <strike>15</strike> 0 are also tagged [`dependency`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic+dependencies) - should be retagged to [circular-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-dependency)*.
- <strike>5</strike> 0 are also tagged [`reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic+reference) - should be retagged to [circular-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/circular-reference)*.
- <strike>4</strike> 0 are also tagged [`import`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic+import) - should be retagged to either of the two above.

From a quick overview, there are more questions that fit to one of the above retag proposals that are not tagged with the base tag. I'm also sure there are some off-topic/low-quality questions that could be closed/deleted.

With the leftovers after the above cleanup, a synonym to [cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cycle) might be created. Its usage guidance says:

> a process or series of items, which repeats several times.

The above synonym proposal is open for discussion as I'm not sure it will necessarily hold for all questions. We can at least be sure that by creating a synonym we avoid `cyclic` being created again and us having to clean it up again. It just feels so *cyclic*…

---

<sup>* The tags [cyclic-dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-dependency) and [cyclic-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cyclic-reference) also exist, and should probably become synonyms of the `circular-` ones. The one for dependency [is already proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/circular-dependency/synonyms).</sup>

Comment: As someone that works with package manager, cyclic-dependencies should not exist as tag. Use the package manager tag instead (or its equivalent).

Comment: @Braiam - cyclic dependency problem is not confined to package management issues. A quick example is the JS modules and corresponding algorithms of cycle resolutions. Take a look at [node.js][cyclic-dependency] [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcyclic-dependency%5D+%5Bnode.js%5D&searchOn=3) for confirmation. No need to jump to burninations.

Comment: @OlegValter yes, it's not confined to package manager because package managers solve it definitively, ie. not allowing it at all. If npm/node.js repository maintainers can't make sure that modules don't depend upon themselves, that's on them. Programmers shouldn't have to worry about that (oh hey, the top answer on all those post say the same thing).

Comment: I disagree. The proper (or: more popular) terms are [[tag:circular-reference]] and [[tag:circular-dependency]]. The cyclic-… ones should be synonymised.

Comment: @Bergi How is that a disagreement? If you agree to the retag proposal, then the exact target or making the synonym is another issue... I mean, if I would change to your proposed tags would you agree with this answer?

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes, I'm ok with the general approach, but you should change the proposed retagging targets

Comment: @Bergi Will do. I agree (wasn't aware of those tags). Don't know if it's you, but `circular-dependency` already has a synonym proposal to the cyclic one

Comment: Yes that was me :-) For circular-references, I have not enough upvotes on my single answer in that tag

Comment: @Bergi That is probably a different discussion (although related) but looking at the wikis of `cyclic/circular-dependency/reference` there is quite a mix-up and I wonder if those should all be merged in some way...